# How to include files in lib folder using Maven-ear-plugin?

Tags: maven, maven-3

I´m using Maven 3 with eclipse and I need to move some files *.properties to default lib bundle dir in EAR file.

Here´s my code:

```
<!-- language-all: lang-xml -->

<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.4.1</version>
<configuration>
    <version>5</version>
    <defaultLibBundleDir>lib</defaultLibBundleDir>
    <archive>
        <manifest>
            <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
            <addDefaultSpecificationEntries>true</addDefaultSpecificationEntries>
        </manifest>
        <manifestEntries>
            <Built-on>${maven.build.timestamp}</Built-on>
            <Developed-by>${project.organization.name}</Developed-by>
            <Revision>${buildNumber}</Revision>
        </manifestEntries>  
    </archive>
</configuration>
</plugin>
```

I have this properties files in the path: src/main/resources and I need to copy to default lib bundle dir, how I do this?

Comment: Hi ricardo, i am not familiar whith the place of DefaultLibBundleDir. Please describe the folder structure of the ear and where you would like to putin the property files.

Comment: In my mind, this is a ear file structure:
http://documentation.progress.com/output/Iona/e2a/asp/6.0/j2ee/reference/EARSCO_ref4.html

Answer (score -1):

Use maven-resources-plugin to copy properties files into lib folder, and maven-ear-plugin will automatically package the files into ear, thank you~